# How to join two tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, concatenation

I have two tensors of dimension [3,1]. I need to join them as a [3,2] tensor.

```
t = torch.tensor([[3.],[1],[2]], requires_grad=True)
x = torch.tensor([[1.],[4],[5]], requires_grad=True)
```

I tried `torch.cat` and `torch.stack` but neither work for me.

Comment: `torch.cat([t,x], axis=1)`

Comment: If my answer solved your question, would you mind clicking the 'accept answer' button?

Answer (score 1):

With `cat` you need to specify the dimension the tensors are concatenated along. By default this is `0`, but you wish to use `1`:

```
import torch
res = torch.cat([t,x], axis=1)
```